# checking if a MS access database exists using VBscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

I have been searching for ages using different search terms but cannot find the answer to my problem.

I am using asp to manipulate an MS Access database which is held in a folder above the root folder.

To connect to the database I use the following code, which works:

```
set Conn = server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
conn.ConnectionString="DBQ=" & server.mappath("../../db") & "\renewx.mdb"& ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
```

However, I want to check that the database exists before I connect, and here I am having some difficulty.

My code for this is:

```
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../../db") & "\renewx.mdb") then
  response.write("renewx dbase exists!<br>")
else
  response.write("renewx dbase does not exist!<br>")
 set fs=nothing
response.end
end if
set fs=nothing
```

This produces the error:

> 800a01a8|Object_required:_'File' HTTP/1.1 (the line triggering the
>   error is the first line of the if condition)

many thanks if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Tog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'if File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../../db") & "\renewx.mdb") then
if fs.FileExists(Server.MapPath("../../db") & "\renewx.mdb") then
```

Comment: adding the fs. in the if statement worked perfectly thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure parent paths are enabled on the IIS server. They come disabled as default.
 [Link to Microsoft documentation for IIS 8](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default)

Comment: The parent paths were enabled, but I marked your answer up because it has merit :-)